# Fast multi-key lookup without Dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, search, .net-4.0, lookup

I have an Id mapping cache that's taking up a bit too much memory. It's used to house a combination of 3 different types of Id's for an object and the mappings for them are read in from a table, and cached in 6 different dictionaries for quick look-up/translation from any 1 Id type to another (performance is important for my application).

I wanted to rewrite it to something that has a smaller memory footprint so I did implement a consolidated list of the Id's and used a linq/lambda expression to pull out the values I wanted. It looks like this for now.

```
public struct IdMappings
{
     public int Id1;
     public int Id2;
     public int Id3;
}

//new cache    
private static List<IdMappings> AllIdMappings = null;

//current cache implementation
private static Dictionary<int, int> Id1ToId2 = null;
private static Dictionary<int, int> Id1ToId3 = null;
//etc.

public static void FillCache(DataSet data)
{
     foreach (DataRow r in data.Tables[0].Rows)
     {
          //fill list and/or dictionaries with id's
     }
}
```

Example lookup would then be:

```
public static int GetId2FromId1(int id1)
{
    return AllIdMappings.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id1 == id1).Id2;
    //or
    return Id1ToId2[id1];
}
```

This does what I need in terms of reducing memory usage, but performance for lookups has suffered as a result so I'm seeing how to implement something different. Is there a way to do multi-indexing keys, or multi-key lookup that's relatively faster than iterating through a list?

Comment: `This does what I need in terms of reducing memory usage, but performance for lookups has suffered as a result` - is it possible that this is because you no longer have the objects prepared in memory, and so need to retrieve them from your database once you've found the ID? i.e. it's a lazy-load rather than eager load. Are you sure the performance hit is taking place in the 'lookup' rather than the 'retrieval'?

Comment: Cache is filled at app start, so only once. Dictionary/hashset are designed for fast lookup, on the order of O(1). I do believe using a list with linq will always be O(n) because it will iterate over the entire the list to find a match.

Comment: if that was in response to my comment, when you say 'cache is filled' do you mean with `objects` or `keys`? If you're retrieving the objects up front, you might as well create a dictionary of the objects rather than their key - no memory benefit to be had. And if you're not retrieving the objects, then after finding the appropriate key you will need to get the corresponding object from the database, which will lead to a longer execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add these three dictionaries:

```
private static Dictionary<int, IdMappings> Id1Lookup = null;
private static Dictionary<int, IdMappings> Id2Lookup = null;
private static Dictionary<int, IdMappings> Id3Lookup = null;
```

And have the dictionary values be the same references, it should use minimally more memory but retain the same lookup speed as your original implementation.

If I'm thinking about this right, this should use half the memory of your 6 dictionary solution, but twice a `List<IdMappings>` type solution.

As @SWeko points out, `IdMappings` needs to be a `class` not a `struct` to ensure the reference pointer is used rather than copies of it.

Comment: For this the OP would also likely need to redefine `IdMappings` to a `class` instead of a `struct`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sort the list and use binary search (List<> already implements this for you in the method Find)
Maintaining a sorted list and lookups is then done in O(logn).

Answer (score 1):

One potential performance improvement could be to use a `Hashset<IdMappings>` instead of a `List<IdMappings>`, but that would mostly help for direct look-up, and not for `FirstOrDefault` which, more or less, iterates the list sequentially.

If your lookups are all from the ID1 -> ID2 and ID3 direction, you could use a `Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>>` for the keys, and that would eliminate a extra value of ID1 from the current dictionaries.

Anyway, cache is by definition trade of memory for lookup speed, so I don't think you can improve the memory consumption by much.

Comment: They are 6 different lookups, hence the 6 different Dictionaries for the original implementation: id1 -> id2, id1 -> id3, id2 -> id1, id2 -> id3, id3 -> id1, id3 -> id2

Comment: @Tom: Then you would need three `Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>` and that would (I think) cut your memory footprint by about 25%.

Comment: Roughly so yes. It's along the same lines as Thymine's answer above, which is good.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best bet is to create a mapping structure:

```
struct Mapping: IComparable<Mapping>
{
    private readonly int FromId;
    private readonly int ToId;
    public Mapping(int fid, int tid);
    // implement the IComparable.Compare method to compare FromId
}
```

Then, create a `List<Mapping>` for each index, and sort the list. You can then use `List.Find` to find the item you want.